# Image Changing in HTML and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a personal coin flip project in HTML and Javascript. Is there a way to make the an image change based on the result of the "flip". For instance if it lands on *heads* it shows an image of a quarter on its *heads* side and same for tails?

Javascript Code:

```
document.getElementById('click').onclick = click;

var heads = 0;
var tails = 0;
function click() {  
    x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
    if(x){
        flip("heads");
    }else{
        flip("tails");
    }
};
function flip(coin) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = coin;
};
```

HTML Code:

```
<button id="click" type="button">CLICK ME</button>
<p>You got: <span id="result"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the working code you just need this...

```
var coins = {
    heads: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/heads is sports',
    tails: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/tails is animals',
}
document.getElementById("result").setAttribute('src', coins[coin])
```

```js
    document.getElementById('click').onclick = click;

    var heads = 0;
    var tails = 0;
    var coins = {
        heads: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/heads is sports',
        tails: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/tails is animals',
    }
    function click() {  
        var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? 'heads' : 'tails';
        flip(result)
    };

    function flip(coin) {
        document.getElementById("result").setAttribute('src', coins[coin])
    };
```

```html
    <button id="click" type="button">CLICK ME</button>
    <p>You got: <img id="result" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `.src` on an `<img />`:
*(The `link` can be anything you want, including a relative path, for example: `"../../img/"`)*

```js
document.getElementById('click').onclick = click;

var heads = 0;
var tails = 0;
function click() {  
  x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
  if(x){
    flip("head");
  }else{
    flip("tail");
  }
};
function flip(coin) {
  var link = "http://www.marshu.com/articles/images-website/articles/presidents-on-coins/half-dollar-coin-";
  document.getElementById("result").src = link+coin+".jpg";
};
```

```css
img {width:100px;}
```

```html
<button id="click" type="button">CLICK ME</button>
<p>You got: <img id="result" src="" /></p>
```